# Setting up searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to setup searchkick on c9.io. I've installed elasticsearch however, I'm unable to access localhost or my URL that's given to me by c9.io on port 9200 to verify that searchkick is working correctly. Has anyone run into this issue?

I've verified that elasticsearch is working.

```
$ /home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/bin/brew info elasticsearch
elasticsearch: stable 1.7.1, HEAD
Distributed real-time search & analytics engine for the cloud
https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch
/home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.7.1 (33 files, 30M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com//homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
==> Caveats
Data:    /home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_ubuntu/
Logs:    /home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_ubuntu.log
Plugins: /home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/
Config:  /home/ubuntu/.linuxbrew/etc/elasticsearch/
```

When I run the rake this is the error message I get.

```
$rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Account
rake aborted!
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
ect...
```

I'm thinking if I can't find a solution to this problem I will set up a local environment but I really don't want to do that.

Comment: "connection refused". either it's not running, not listening on that ip/port combo, or it's firewalled.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running this on my mac. Sine the version you installed doesn't automatically run as a daemon you will get connection refused. It's better to install the package if you are running ubuntu. There is a guide on the elasticsearch site that is easy to follow. Use the steps on the site below and give it another shot.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't installed searchkick but I've been working on ElasticSearch in C9 environment.

These are the steps I did:

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/deb/elasticsearch/2.2.0/elasticsearch-2.2.0.deb

sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-2.2.0.deb

sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10

sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

Then I modified the elasticsearch.yml file to include a supported port by the c9.io (8081 or 8082 for instance): uncomment the host port in the file and modify this port number.

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Finally make an elasticsearch initializer (config/initializes/elasticsearch.rb) and include the c9 IP:

```
"Your Model to be indexed".__elasticsearch__.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: ENV['IP']
```

Hope this will help, because the port problem of elasticsearch on C9 environment is not well documented.